Unable to run dotnet app in IIS due to Mime type
While opening the dotnet app website in IIS, when i browse the website i get the below error. I have saved the app code in inetpub/wwwroot directory with path of the IIS pool set at inetpub/wwwroot/drop/app.sln
HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map. 

